# How to set authorization header in SoapUIProTestCaseRunner?

Tags: java, ready-api

While integrating ReadyAPI tests with Java code, how to set authorization? I get error:

> ```
> #status# : HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in java console
> ```

```
SoapUIProTestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUIProTestCaseRunner();
runner.setProjectFile("C://APILOcal//activations.xml");
runner.setTestSuite("ServiceSOAP TestSuite");
runner.setTestCase("createContractBundle TestCase");
runner.setTestStepCount(3);
//runner.setGlobalProperties(new String[]{"Authorization: Basic admin=admin"});
//runner.setCustomHeaders(new String[]{"Authorization: Basic admin=admin"});
//runner.setUsername("admin");
//runner.setPassword("admin");
//runner.setWssPasswordType("PasswordText");
runner.run();
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Request(s) inside your SOAPUI project must have Authorization. User Name/Password values there can be set explicitly or to the Custom Properties from any level Project, Test Suite etc...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have set the authorization in Ready API ant it runs successfully there. Now I want to trigger the same request from Java. I am using the above Java code for the same . Question here is How to mention the authorization (which is up and running in Ready API ) in Java code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved Now. Initially the authentication was set to test step level. 
After setting up the authentication at project level in ready API and executed the java code , it went through and the request is getting executed successfully. Thanks!